# Zend how do I create a left join

Tags: sql, zend-framework, join

How do I turn this left join query:

```
select advertisercontest.*, advertiseraccount.advertiserid, advertiseraccount.companyname
from advertisercontest
left join advertiseraccount on advertiseraccount.loginid = advertisercontest.loginid 
where advertisercontest.golive is not NULL;
```

into a left join in Zend?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could do as follows:

```
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

    $select = $db->select();
    $select->from('advertisercontest', '*')
            ->joinLeft(
                    'advertiseraccount',
                    'advertiseraccount.loginid = advertisercontest.loginid',
                    array('advertiseraccount.advertiserid', 'advertiseraccount.companyname')
                    )
            ->where('advertisercontest.golive is not NULL');;

    $result = $db->fetchAll($select);

    var_dump($result);
```

Here is the [Zend_Db_Select documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.db.select.html).

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks! I have a question. I'm extending Zend_Db_Table_Abstract and I had this:

$rows = $this->select()->from('advertisercontest', '*')
             ->joinLeft('advertiseraccount', 'advertiseraccount.loginid = advertisercontest.loginid', 
                       array('advertiseraccount.advertiserid', 'advertiseraccount.companyname'))
             ->where('advertisercontest.golive is not NULL')
             ->order('advertisercontestid DESC');

But it did not work? But your example did.. I have in my applications.ini resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true

Comment: @coder3. You cod probably does not work because you need to perform $rows = $this->fetchAll($select). In your case you have $rows which will be just an instance of Zend_Db_Select, not the actual results. Anyway, if you find my answer acceptable, I would be happy if you could accept it. Thanks and hope it will work.